# Add a advanced search webpart to master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, search, master-page, custom-masterpage

I want to add a **advanced search webpart** to master page in SharePoint 2013. I export the advanced search webpart, and then upload it to library in the site. Then I want to do: go to Site Settings -> Design Manager -> Edit Master Page, copy all code and paste it to master page. But the advanced search webpart cannot display in the section Preview. If I add a webpart by default, it displays in the section Preview:
[image]

If I deploy my master page, a error message will appear "One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot deserialize the Web Part.  Check the format of the properties and try again. "

Why this webpart does not work ? Is it possible only webpart by default can be added to master page ?

Comment: Not to be that guy, but why on earth do you want to add the search webpart to the master page and not to a page layout?

Comment: @RobertLindgren I need this webpart displays all the site pages, and users cannot edit it.